# aggregate flow data using typology in R

Tags: aggregate

**Background**: I would like to aggregate flow data. I have a dataframe with origin-destination migration pairs. Origin and Destinations are municipalities and are stored as an id number. Additionally, there are the number of migrations (from origin to destination). Then, i have another dataframe with the municipality id numbers and a typology to which the municipality belongs (urban, suburban, rural..). I now want to aggregate the flows by typology. In the end i want a dataframe with typology-origin typology-destination and the flow numbers.

For example:

**Flow data**

```
migration_df <- data.frame(
  Origin_Municipality_Number = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
  Destination_Municipality_Number = c(3, 1, 2, 3, 1),
  Migration_Number = c(100, 150, 75, 200, 50)
)
```

**Typology**

```
typology_df <- data.frame(
  Municipality_Number = c(1, 2, 3),
  Typology = c("Urban", "Subrban", "Rural")
)
```

I already calculated total numbers of in- and outmigration for each type but this way i lose the direction of flows. In the end, i want to create a alluvial plot (ggalluvial) to show the in-and outflows of the municipality types.